# Which IUser to Use in AcquireTokenSilentAsync in MSAL

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm asking this question in the context of a mobile (Xamarin) app using Azure AD B2C.

**The tl;dr; of this is:**  Should I always use the `IUser` obtained from the “sign-in / sign-up” policy when invoking `PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync`?

Now let me explain a scenario a bit.

A user tries to use an app, but needs to do a password reset immediately.

Using the MSAL library, the `PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync` is called invoking the "reset password" policy.

Assuming a successful call, an `IUser` object is placed in the `PublicClientApplication.Users` collection.

In addition, the token returned in the `AuthenticationResult` from that function is enough to let the user access the resources that need the AD B2C token.

This then means that any future calls to `PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync` would use the `IUser` which was associated with the "reset-password" policy.

It will work ... but is that a best practice?

Or should the app immediately prompt the user to log in, thus invoking the "sign-up/sign-in" policy & thus have the `IUser` associated with that policy added to the `PublicClientApplication.Users` collection. Then whenever the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` is invoked, that particular `IUser` can be passed to it? (Instead of the one from the "reset password" policy.)

The same question can be asked whenever an "profile editing" policy is called. A new `IUser` is added to the collection, and assuming the user has already signed in previous, does it matter which `IUser` is sent to `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt, I suggest you have a look at the following sample [active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native), and it particular the `GetUserByPolicy(IEnumerable<User> users, string policy)` method located in [UserDetailsClient/MainPage.xaml.cs#L76-L85](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient/MainPage.xaml.cs#L76-L85). This method retrieves the right `IUser` to use given a policy.

`foreach (var user in users)
    {
     string userIdentifier = Base64UrlDecode(user.Identifier.Split('.')[0]);
     if (userIdentifier.EndsWith(policy.ToLower())) return user;
    }`

Its usage is also shown in the `OnCallApi` method in [UserDetailsClient/MainPage.xaml.cs#L116](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient/MainPage.xaml.cs#L116)

Comment: As an update, any `IUser` that is returned from the method outlined above will indeed contain a token that works. It is up to the developer whether or not they want to use that token, or force the user to log in again if the token is not from the proper policy.